# converting infix to postfix (assignment operator included) using c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to convert to an infix expression to postfix in c++. I have done coding with simple operators /,*,+,- but **I am confused about the logic for assignment operator(=).** I know it must be given the lowest precedence but for input like A=B=4 or A=(B=2)*2, how can I decide the precedence. My code is written below. (without implementation for assignment operator).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


// Simply determine if character is one of the four standard operators.
bool isOperator(char character) {
if (character == '+' || character == '-' || character == '*' || character == '/' || character=='=') {
    return true;
}
return false;
}


// If the character is not an operator or a parenthesis, then it is assumed to be an operand.
bool isOperand(char character) {
if (!isOperator(character) && character != '(' && character != ')') {
    return true;
}
return false;
}


// Compare operator precedence of main operators.
// Return 0 if equal, -1 if op2 is less than op1, and 1 if op2 is greater than op1.
int compareOperators(char op1, char op2) {
if ((op1 == '*' || op1 == '/') && (op2 == '+' || op2 == '-')) { return -1; }
else if ((op1 == '+' || op1 == '-') && (op2 == '*' || op2 == '/')) { return 1; }
return 0;
}


int main()
{
// Empty character stack and blank postfix string.
stack<char> opStack;
string postFixString = "";

char input[100];

// Collect input
cout << "Enter an expression: ";
cin >> input;

// Get a pointer to our character array.
char *cPtr = input;

// Loop through the array (one character at a time) until we reach the end of the string.
while (*cPtr != '\0') {
    // If operand, simply add it to our postfix string.
    // If it is an operator, pop operators off our stack until it is empty, an open parenthesis or an operator with less than or equal precedence.
    if (isOperand(*cPtr)) { postFixString += *cPtr; }
    else if (isOperator(*cPtr)) {
        while (!opStack.empty() && opStack.top() != '(' && compareOperators(opStack.top(), *cPtr) <= 0) {
            postFixString += opStack.top();
            opStack.pop();
        }
        opStack.push(*cPtr);
    }
    // Simply push all open parenthesis onto our stack
    // When we reach a closing one, start popping off operators until we run into the opening parenthesis.
    else if (*cPtr == '(') { opStack.push(*cPtr); }
    else if (*cPtr == ')') {
        while (!opStack.empty()) {
            if (opStack.top() == '(') { opStack.pop(); break; }
            postFixString += opStack.top();
            opStack.pop();
        }
    }

    // Advance our pointer to next character in string.
    cPtr++;
}

// After the input expression has been ran through, if there is any remaining operators left on the stack
// pop them off and put them onto the postfix string.
while (!opStack.empty()) {
    postFixString += opStack.top();
    opStack.pop();
}


// Show the postfix string at the end.
cout << "Postfix is: " << postFixString << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Precedence is not everything. You might want to learn about [*operator associativity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) as well. You have to decide if `A = B = C` is the same as `(A = B) = C` or `A = (B = C)` (C++ is the second, right associative).

Comment: If you want to support more operators, then it's time to refactor your code. A function like `compareOperators` would quickly grow in complexity as it is written. As easy improvement would be to add a function that returns the precedence level of an operator and then you would compare the result. Alternatively, you might want to keep some extra information for each operator like associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it the same precedence as the *operands*, and see what you get:

```
// Simply determine if character is one of the four standard operators.
bool isOperator(char character) {
if (character == '+' || character == '-' || character == '*' || character == '/') {
    //|| character=='='
    return true;
}
return false;
}

// If the character is not an operator or a parenthesis, then it is assumed to be an operand.
bool isOperand(char character) {
//for =, treat it wth the same rules as the operands; push to output
if (character == '='){
    return true;
}
if (!isOperator(character) && character != '(' && character != ')') {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```